# How to create a very large array of unique integers?

Tags: c++, arrays, random, numbers

Part of an assignment for my parallel programming class is to create a file of 313 million unique integers. I figure I'll multiply two random numbers together to get a very large range, but what is the best way to check for uniqueness?

Should I create an array and search the array each time for matches? That seems as though it will be very inefficient.

Edit - the problem is to eventually sort the list (using threading / multi cores) so having a sequential list doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could fill the file up sequentially - the resulting file would look like:

> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ... 312999999

These numbers would be very simple to generate, and would be guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: yes you are right, sorry for not clarifying, our problem is to eventually sort the numbers (using threads / multiple cores) so having them sequential wont work (they have to be unsorted)

Comment: @ewagness Generate them like Mankarse says, then do a random shuffle.

Comment: is there a random shuffle for c++ ? or just python

Comment: @ewagness [std::random_shuffle](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) in `<algorithm>`

Comment: the shuffling is a great working idea, the problem now is that you can only create an array so large, for our lab machines this is about 250k, so you cant have all 313 million integers in one (or multiple) arrays

Comment: @ewagness: Store all the numbers using a fixed width format -- this will allow you to randomly index into the file. Then you need to write an iterator that will do this random iteration ([fstream::seekg](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) and [fstream::seekp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/seekp) could be useful for implementing this). Have a look at [STXXL](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/) -- I've never used it, but if it works as advertised it might make your job a bit easier.

Comment: @Mankarse thank you so much, I was trying to do this, using a set of exact numbers(1-313mil) and putting them at random locations, but I could not figure out how to access the file at a certain index. much apreciated

Answer (score 2):

For parallel programming assignment, I think maybe you need to divide the task into small and independent pieces.
As 313M is still litter than 2G which is the maximum number a 32bit can represent.
My suggestion is that you can break the 32bit number into 16bit higher and 16bit lower. For each thread you assign a fixed higher bits and the thread generate the lower 16bits. Then you combine the two parts, thus you can keep every number generated by each thread is different.

Comment: yes, i think we will have to try solutions similiar to this, seeing that I cannot create an array bigger than about 250,000